# Amplify Datastore.save does not update backend

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-datastore

Here is the code, and I am trying to update the `ShortId` records

```
await DataStore.save(
                ShortID.copyOf(ShortIDRecord, (updated) => {
                  Object.assign(updated, modelFields);
                })
              );
```

The problem in here is the `_version` var updates but not the `short_id` field.

The input data is `abcdgedefga`, but the return response is original as`abcdged`

```
{
    "data": {
        "updateShortID": {
            "id": "3a83342f-e4f9-4b6b-a91f-d1003277b561",
            "short_id": "abcdged",
            "createdAt": "2023-09-16T06:44:48.037Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-09-16T06:44:48.037Z",
            "_version": 2,
            "_lastChangedAt": 1694846699836,
            "_deleted": null
        }
    }
}
```

ps, also tried the same process with `API.graphql`; the same result of update failure; but `_lastChangedAt` and `_version` are updated, other remain the same

Comment: Resolved!! "Disable conflict detection"